# Solve returns a couple of wrong solutions to a nonlinear equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to understand what is wrong with the line

```
Solve[c^2*α - c*α*(c + Sqrt[c^2 + 4])/2 + 1 == 0, c]
```

which returns

```
{{c -> -(1/(Sqrt[-1 + α] Sqrt[α]))}, {c -> 1/(Sqrt[-1 + α] Sqrt[α])}}
```

both are not solutions to the equation as per manual check.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Sqrt` is a multivalued function and the answer depends on which branch cut you take. Further, MMA assumes, without further info, that all variables are complex. Therefore, if you know that e.g. alpha and c are real, you may specify this like:

```
sol = Solve[{c^2*α - c*α*(c + Sqrt[c^2 + 4])/2 + 1 == 0, {α, c} ∈ Reals}, c]
```

[image]

```
c^2*\[Alpha] - c*\[Alpha]*(c + Sqrt[c^2 + 4])/2 + 1 /. sol  // Simplify
```

[image]

For problems like this, `Reduce` may give you more information

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! It actually makes a lot of sense.